# In mysql, how can I update timestamp type?

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

Hi I have a table which have timestamp value, when I write that in php

> mysql_query("UPDATE table SET
>   date=$newdate WHERE
>   name=ibrahim");

it does not work. $newdate is a string value that I read from same table before. How can I change date column? thanks for help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put string values (including date literals) in quotes for MySQL.

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE table SET date='$newdate' WHERE name='ibrahim'")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET date='{$newdate}' WHERE name='ibrahim'"); //quote your strings
```

Comment: @Daric <smacks head> you're right of course. I was treating it as a PHP variable and not a string literal. @Wh1T3h4Ck5 see above, that was a mistake!